# Fatal Error :: Call to undefined method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have Placed the codeigniter code controller and it throws a error Call to undefined method CI_Controller::CI_Controller().Pls help me to rectify the issue.
 Controller:

```
<?php

class Site1 extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
    parent::CI_Controller ();
    $this->is_logged_in();
    }

    function members_area()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');


    }

    function another_page() // just for sample
    {
        echo 'good. you\'re logged in.';
    }

    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
        {
            echo 'You don\'t have permission to access this page. <a href="../login">Login</a>';    
            die();      
            //$this->load->view('login_form');
        }       
    }   

}
```

Comment: replace parent::CI_Controller (); with parent::__construct();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you call the parent constructor. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

```
parent::__construct();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a latest version of CodeIgniter replace this line of code with this:

From `parent::CI_Controller ();` to `parent::__construct();`

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a parent constructor, one would have to explicitly call `parent::__construct()`

```
function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   $this->is_logged_in();
}
```

Ex: Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

```
 class SubClass extends BaseClass {
   function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   print "In SubClass constructor\n";
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CI 2.x then your class constructor should look like this:

```
   public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
   }
```

read more in [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#constructors)